# Extension $\sigma$-algebra $\{A\subset\Omega:\exists B \text{ so that } A\Delta B \text{ is a null set}\}$ is $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space.
>   Then, the completion $\sigma$-algebra is given by
>   $$
> \mathcal{G}
> := \{A\subset\Omega \mid \exists B \text{ so that } A\Delta B \text{ is a } \mu\text{-null set}\}
> $$
>   and the completing measure by $\bar{\mu}(A) := \mu(B)$.

I want to verify that $\mathcal{G}$ is $\sigma$-algebra, but struggle to prove that $A \in \mathcal{G} \implies A^C \in \mathcal{G}$.

*Note:*
I know that one can show $\mathcal{G} = \{ A \cup N: A \subset \Omega, N \text{ is a } \mu\text{-null set} \}$, which is trivially a $\sigma$-algebra, but want to show this for this specific representation.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\in\mathcal{G}$ then there is a set $B$ such that $A\Delta B$ is null. Now note that:

$A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)=(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)=(B^c\setminus A^c)\cup (A^c\setminus B^c)=A^c\Delta B^c$.

So for $A^c$ there is the set $B^c$ such that $A^c\Delta B^c$ is null.